# Can't make the button refer to another activity in android

Tags: java, android, button

I want the button to show some texts when it is clicked. When we click the 'formula' button, a new blank page should open up in the phone showing the layout of the activity.. Here are my codes

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "";

    // ....

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FormulaActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
     // Do something in response to button
    startActivity(intent);
```

**FormulaActivity.java**

```
public class FormulaActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }
```

**MainActivity.xml** (button coding)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/formula"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="Formula" />
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Do you face any crash ?

Comment: Can you explain the problem ? What is happening when you click on your button ?

Comment: Please refer some tutorial and read basic things about android.

Comment: NOTHING is happening when I press the 'formula' button

Comment: in which activity you have formula button and also do you used onclicklistener for button click ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to intialize the `Button` and `EditText` inside your `MainActivity.java`

`XML Layout File`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />

   <Button 
    android:id="@+id/formula"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Formula"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    />
```

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Button F=(Button)findViewById(R.id.formula);
     EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

      F.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener()
       {
          public void onClick()
          {
            sendMessage(); 
          }
       }

    }

    public void sendMessage() 
      {
      String message = editText.getText().toString();
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FormulaActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", message);       
      startActivity(intent);
      }
  }
```

---

```
public class FormulaActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "";
```

is empty string. Try changing it to any valued string.

Hope this will help you.